# Application lifetime persistent storage in android application

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, data-storage

I want my application to store some data for lifetime of application.
I know that there are 4 types of data storage in android.
1: Shared Preference
2: Internal Storage
3: External Storage (I don't want to use this as it includes extra permission)
4: SQLite Database
5: Network connection (I cant use this as i want to target users who don't have data connection).

Data stored by method 1,2,4 are not reliable as user can clear application data from application manager.
Is there any other way to achieve this objective?

Comment: How about making a service and storing data in memory? You don't give much of a choice...

Comment: Sorry didn't got you.. can you elaborate on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Data stored by method 1,2,4 are not reliable as user can clear application data from application manager.

If your objective is to put data on users' devices that they cannot remove, that is not possible in standard versions of Android by SDK applications. The user is in control over their device, not you, and therefore they can get rid of your data (and your app, for that matter) whenever they wish.

Comment: is there a work around i want to store some key value pairs.
if i add write external storage permission then?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel: The user can delete data that is stored anywhere on their device, including external storage. If you do not want the user to delete data, **do not put it on their device**.